# CSS class nesting

Tags: css

I havent done CSS in awhile (~5-7yrs).

So i need a little assistance in a possible solution to my quandry.

Ideal design:

```
table.ctable
{ class:collapsible collapsed; }
```

Now i know that its syntactically not correct but was wondering if there was a way to create some base-class CSS and then have those class(es) derive into a parent.  I know its not OOP, but figured there would be a way around the current structure to accomidate this type of inclusion.

Comment: Are you trying to access the elements of a certain class that are inside an element of a certain class? Or are you trying to set the class via css?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You couls use a [SASS mixin](http://sass-lang.com/):

```
@mixin left($dist) {
  float: left;
  margin-left: $dist;
}

#data {
  @include left(10px);
}
```

or a [LessCSS mixin](http://lesscss.org/#-mixins):

```
.left(@dist) {
  float: left;
  margin-left: @dist;
}

#data {
  .left(10px);
}
```

Comment: Hm, I'm not familiar with that software, I guess it depends how it serves up css content. If you can add a filter, then LessCSS might be a good fit, I think that it is a superset of css, so normal css would pass right though as-is.

Comment: Looks like i can use Sass to develop the style and then "compile" it to spit out the actuall CSS style.  I assume that SASS is a free software?

Comment: Compiling works, you can set it up to watch for changes to your source file, so that it will automatically recompile. SASS is released under an [MIT license](https://github.com/nex3/sass/blob/master/MIT-LICENSE).

Answer (score 1):

No, unfortunately you can't inherit rules from another class. The closest you can get is JavaScript getting elements by class name and applying extra classes to them, but then you have the jump between the page loading the JS running.